# Safeguarding node passwords

Tags: node.js, database, windows, security

In my development environment for a node API I'm using an env file to store the passwords. As I understand it, it isn't recommended to use this approach in a production environment, which is on a windows server. So the passwords are in a bat file which sets them as process variables. But this leaves the issue of the bat file which is lying around. So I'm looking for way to secure this information. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to best practice?

Comment: Why [[tag:dos]]?

Comment: What's a "node password"?